# value < is not a member of AnyVal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shortest-path

I have been writing a code in scala to find the shortest path. This is my code for finding Shortest-Path. But I am getting an error in the following part of code

```
if ( (kv1._1 + kv1._2 )< (kv2._1 + kv2._2)) kv1 else kv2
```

The error is

```
value < is not a member of AnyVal
```

Here is my code:

```
 val inputRDD = sc.textFile(args(0)).map { line =>
  val a = line.split(",")
  (a(0).toLong, (a(1).toLong, a(2).toLong))
}
var distanceRDD = inputRDD.flatMap(x => {
  val pair1 = if (x._1 == 0) (x._1, 0) else (x._1, Long.MaxValue)
  val pair2 = if (x._2._1 == 0) (x._2._1, 0) else (x._2._1, Long.MaxValue)

  List(pair1, pair2)
}).distinct()

for ( index <- 1 to 4 ) {
  val vertexDistanceRDD=  inputRDD.join(distanceRDD)   

  val invertedRDD =vertexDistanceRDD.map(attr => (attr._2._1._2,(attr._2._1._1,attr._2._2)))

  val computedDistBetweenVertRDD =invertedRDD.reduceByKey((kv1, kv2) => {

    if (kv1._2 == kv2._2) if (kv1._1 < kv2._1) kv1 else kv2
    else if (kv1._2.<(kv2._2)){
      if ( kv2._2 != Long.MaxValue) {
        if ( (kv1._1 + kv1._2 )< (kv2._1 + kv2._2)) kv1 else kv2
      }
      else  kv1
    }
    else {
      if ( kv1._2 != Long.MaxValue) {
        if (kv1._1 + kv1._2 < kv2._1 + kv2._2) kv1 else kv2
      }
      else  kv2
    }
  })

  val joinedRDD = computedDistBetweenVertRDD.join(distanceRDD)
  distanceRDD =joinedRDD.map(kv => {
    if (kv._2._2 > kv._2._1._1 + kv._2._1._2) (kv._1,kv._2._1._1 + kv._2._1._2) else (kv._1,kv._2._2)
  })
}
```

What could be the possible reason and how can I rectify it?

Comment: what's the type of `invertedRDD`?

Comment: invertedRDD is of Long type

Comment: that can't be the case - `reduceByKey` can only operation in PairRDDs, meaning the RDD must have the type `RDD[(K, V)]` for some types K and V - can you check what V is? Looking at your code, V must be some kind of tuple itself, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `kv1._1` and `kv1._2`. Please show how `invertedRdd` is created if you're unsure how to conclude its type.

Comment: I have added the full code. Please tell what needs to be changed and where

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression

```
if (x._1 == 0) (x._1, 0) else (x._1, Long.MaxValue)
```

has type `(Long, AnyVal)` because `0` is an `Int` literal (in this case it is not implicitly converted to `Long`) and least upper bound of `Int` and `Long` is `AnyVal`. Correct code should be

```
if (x._1 == 0) (x._1, 0L) else (x._1, Long.MaxValue)
//                     ^ use Long literal there
```

Same applies to your second `if`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a type bound on your arguments `kv1` and `kv2`. Without the type information, the compiler can only infer that you are using anonymous objects (`AnyVal` type), which does not have a comparison operator defined on it.

Comment: that's not generally true - the compiler can usually infer types of anonymous function's arguments. For example, if `invertedRDD` had type `RDD[(Int, Int)]`, then - this compiles: `invertedRDD.reduceByKey((kv1, kv2) => kv1 + kv2)`

Comment: Agreed that Scala often has such information. However, the type signature of `reduceByKey()` is not that helpful.

Comment: How so? For an `RDD[(K, V)]`, `reduceByKey` takes an argument of type `(V, V) => V` - this means the function argument type need _not_ be explicitly stated. The problem here probably has to do with the type of `invertedRDD` to begin with

Comment: You are correct, Tzach, on the first count. Likely on the second point, as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if there is a type mismatch.

I encountered the same issue while working with lists of tuples

input:

```
val L = List((1,"Raja",2000.0),(2,"Fahad",1000000.0),(3,"shoaib",40023.0),(4,"azeez",89890))
```

output:

```
L: List[(Int, String, AnyVal)] = List((1,Raja,2000.0), (2,Fahad,1000000.0), (3,shoaib,40023.0), (4,azeez,89890))
```

input:

```
L.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toUpperCase, if(x._3 > 10000) x._3+x._3*0.1 else x._3))
```

output:

> :28: error: value > is not a member of AnyVal
>
> ```
>          L.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toUpperCase, if(x._3 > 10000) x._3+x._3*0.1 else x._3))
>                                                      ^
> ```

I resolved it by making the AnyVal to Double for the tuple (4,azeez,89890)  => (4,azeez,89890.0)

// AFTER FIX

Input:

```
scala> val L = List((1,"Raja",2000.0),(2,"Fahad",1000000.0),(3,"shoaib",40023.0),(4,"azeez",89890.0))
```

output:

```
L: List[(Int, String, Double)] = List((1,Raja,2000.0), (2,Fahad,1000000.0), (3,shoaib,40023.0), (4,azeez,89890.0))
```

Input:

```
scala> L.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toUpperCase, if(x._3 > 10000) x._3+x._3*0.1 else x._3))
```

output:

```
res44: List[(Int, String, Double)] = List((1,RAJA,2000.0), (2,FAHAD,1100000.0), (3,SHOAIB,44025.3), (4,AZEEZ,98879.0))
```